# Keyboard problem how to substitute a letter

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Hi An old but good Laptop has a problem with the keyboard. The <kbd>W</kbd> key has stopped working. I have dismantled the key but it doesn't want to know. I am entering the <kbd>W</kbd>  from a usb keyboard here..
As Its only 1 key I thought to see if I can put the <kbd>W</kbd>  on another key like the windows key or somewhere.
Any Ideas and how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`xmodmap`](http://cweiske.de/howto/xmodmap/allinone.html) (I know it's a very basic-*looking* page but all the information is there) to reallocate keys.

Personally, I'd look at getting a replacement keyboard:

- Ebay
- 2nd hand shops
- Computer disposal companies
- The original manufacturer

Ebay and 2nd hand shops are more likely to sell you working models but plenty of "for parts" sales happen on Ebay, very cheaply. There is the possibility you'll end up with another broken keyboard though.

Computer disposal firms might be able to help you out too. They tend to deal with thousands of laptops so might not want to help, but they're probably your best bet because of the volume they deal with.

And finally, it might be worth having a word with the people who made the laptop. Companies do hoard spare parts for service needs so unless it's really *very* old, they might have a shiny new keyboard. They won't let you have it cheaply though.

Comment: thanks its an old but good core duo laptop so not practical to repair. I looked at xmodmap but my home directory says I am not the owner(dont know why) and need permissions to  create xmodmap. after which I have seen how to do it I think..thanks